# Shader ported from shadertoy does not behave in the same way

Tags: shader, glsl, godot

I tried porting the main "Image" shader here [this](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tt3yR2). My results are somewhat similar apart from the fact that "IRES" does not seem to behave in the same way as it does in Shadertoy. It is supposed to alter the "resolution" of the fake "CRT" monitor, but when I apply this to a `color rect` and alter "IRES" it will just zoom on the upper left corner of the scene behind it. How can I alter the code below to make it behave similarly to the original shader?

```
shader_type canvas_item;

#define gaussian(a,b)   exp2((a)*(a)*-(b))

uniform sampler2D SCREEN_TEXTURE : hint_screen_texture, filter_linear_mipmap;

uniform float SCREEN_CURVE_RADIUS = 5;
uniform float SCREEN_CORNER_RADIUS = 0.1;
uniform float BRIGHTNESS = 1.5;
uniform float PIXEL_SHARPNESS = 2.0;
uniform float LINE_SHARPNESS = 6.0;
uniform float MASK_STRENGTH = 0.15;

uniform bool CURVE_SCREEN = true;
uniform bool SCANLINES = true;
uniform bool SHADOW_MASK = true;
uniform bool LIGHT_EFFECTS = true;

uniform float TILES = 2.0;
const vec2 IRES = vec2(16, 9) * 5.0;

vec3 ACESFilm(vec3 x) {
    return clamp((x*(2.51*x + 0.03)) / (x*(2.43*x + 0.59) + 0.14), 0.0, 1.0);
}

vec2 curveScreen(vec2 uv) {
    float r = 3.14159265 * 0.5 / SCREEN_CURVE_RADIUS;
    float d = 1.0-cos(uv.x*r)*cos(uv.y*r);      // distance to screen
    float s = cos(r);                           // scale factor to re-fit window
    return uv / (1.0-d) * s;
}

float discardCorners(vec2 pos) {
    pos = abs(pos);
    pos.x = pos.x*1.333-0.333;                                          // 4:3 aspect ratio correction
    if (min(pos.x, pos.y) < 1.0-SCREEN_CORNER_RADIUS) return 1.0;       // not near corner -- break early
    float d = distance(pos, vec2(1.0 - SCREEN_CORNER_RADIUS));
    return float(d < SCREEN_CORNER_RADIUS);
}

vec3 getSample(vec2 pos, vec2 off) {
    //get nearest emulated sample
    vec2 ir = IRES * TILES;
    pos = floor(pos*ir) + vec2(0.5) + off;
    vec3 col = vec3(0.0);
    if ( pos.x>=0.0 && pos.x<=ir.x*2.0 && pos.y>=0.0 && pos.y<=ir.y ) {
        col = texelFetch(SCREEN_TEXTURE, ivec2(pos), 0).rgb;
        col = pow( ( (col + 0.055) / 1.055), vec3(2.4) );       // SRGB => linear
    }
    return col;
}

vec3 getScanline( vec2 pos, float off ) {
    // 3-tap gaussian filter to get colour at arbitrary point along scanline
    vec2 ir = IRES * TILES;
    float d = 0.5-fract(pos.x*ir.x);
    vec3 ca = getSample( pos, vec2(-1.0, off ) );
    vec3 cb = getSample( pos, vec2( 0.0, off ) );
    vec3 cc = getSample( pos, vec2( 1.0, off ) );
    float wa = gaussian( d-1.0, PIXEL_SHARPNESS );
    float wb = gaussian( d,     PIXEL_SHARPNESS );
    float wc = gaussian( d+1.0, PIXEL_SHARPNESS );
    return ( ca*wa + cb*wb + cc*wc ) / ( wa+wb+wc);
}

vec3 getScreenColour(vec2 pos) {
    //Get influence of 3 nearest scanlines
    vec2 ir = IRES * TILES;
    float d = 0.5-fract(pos.y*ir.y);
    vec3 ca = getScanline( pos,-1.0 );
    vec3 cb = getScanline( pos, 0.0 );
    vec3 cc = getScanline( pos, 1.0 );
    float wa = gaussian( d-1.0, LINE_SHARPNESS );
    float wb = gaussian( d,     LINE_SHARPNESS );
    float wc = gaussian( d+1.0, LINE_SHARPNESS );
    return ( ca*wa + cb*wb + cc*wc );
}

vec3 SlotMask_PixelPerfect(vec2 pos, float resolution_y) {
    //pos /= 1.0 + floor( resolution_y / 1440.0 );
    pos /= 1.0 + floor(resolution_y / (IRES.y*15.0));
    float glow = 0.5;
    float f = mod(pos.x,3.0);
    vec3 col = vec3(float(f <= 1.0), float(f > 1.0 && f <= 2.0), float(f > 2.0));
    col += vec3(float(f<1.5 || f>=2.5), float(f>0.5 && f<=2.5), float(f>1.5 || f<=0.5)) * glow;
    col *= (mod(pos.y+(fract(pos.x/6.0)>0.5?1.5:0.0),3.0)<1.0) ? glow : 1.0;
    col /= 1.0+glow;
    return col;
}

void fragment(){
    vec2 uv =  FRAGCOORD.xy / (1.0 / SCREEN_PIXEL_SIZE).xy;
    vec2 pos = SCREEN_UV;
    pos = pos*2.0 - 1.0;
    pos.x *= (1.0 / SCREEN_PIXEL_SIZE).x/(1.0 / SCREEN_PIXEL_SIZE).y*(IRES.y/IRES.x);
    
    if (CURVE_SCREEN) pos = curveScreen(pos);
    
    if(max( abs(pos.x), abs(pos.y) )<1.0) {                         // skip everything if we're beyond the screen edge
        
        vec3 col = vec3(1.0);
        
        if (CURVE_SCREEN) col *= discardCorners(pos);
        
        if (LIGHT_EFFECTS) col *= 1.0 - sqrt(length(pos)*0.25);                     // vignette
        
        pos = pos*0.5 + 0.5;

       if (SCANLINES) col *= getScreenColour( pos );
       else col *= getSample( pos, vec2(0.0) );
        
       if (SHADOW_MASK) {
        vec3 shadowmask = SlotMask_PixelPerfect(FRAGCOORD.xy, (1.0 / SCREEN_PIXEL_SIZE).y);
        col *= mix( vec3(1.0-MASK_STRENGTH), vec3(1.0+MASK_STRENGTH), shadowmask);
        }
        
        if (LIGHT_EFFECTS) {
            col *= BRIGHTNESS;
            col = ACESFilm(col);
        }
    
        col = pow(col, vec3(1.0/2.4)) * 1.055 - 0.055;          // linear => SRGB
    
        COLOR = vec4(col, 1.0);
    }
}
```